# Why does a single SQL query cost me 0.02 sec in the command line but almost 10secs in a Springboot application on the product server?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot

environment: Centos 7, JDK8, Mysql5.6, Springboot 2.1.7.RELEASE
here is the SQL:

```
SELECT alarm.id, alarm.driver, alarm.deviceCode, subway.route, alarm.carNumber, subway.type as carType, alarm.name, alarm.type, alarm.createTime, alarm.path, alarm.alarmVideo, alarm.videoId, alarm.carName
FROM alarm, subway 
WHERE alarm.deviceCode = subway.deviceCode 
      and createTime between '2022-03-03 10:00:12' and '2022-03-04 10:00:13'
      and subway.city like concat('%','ChengDu', '%')
order by createTime
desc limit 15,15
```

and the java is :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getAll", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResultMsg getAll(
        @RequestParam(value = "route", required = false) String route,
        @RequestParam(value = "carNumber", required = false) String carNumber,
        @RequestParam(value = "carType", required = false) String carType,
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
        @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) String type,
        @RequestParam(value = "dateStart", required = false, defaultValue = "") String dateStart,
        @RequestParam(value = "dateEnd", required = false) String dateEnd,
        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = true) int page,
        @RequestParam(value = "size", required = true) int size,
        @RequestParam(value = "city", required = true) String city) {
    if (page == 0)
        page = 1;

    if (null != carNumber) {
        carNumber = carNumber.toLowerCase();
    }
    InetAddress address = null;
    try {
        address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String url = serverIp + "/file/";
    List<Alarm> alarmList = iAlarm.getAll(route, carNumber, carType, name, type, dateStart, dateEnd, page, size, city);
    for (int i = 0; i < alarmList.size(); i++) {
        alarmList.get(i).setAlarmVideo(url + videoUrl + alarmList.get(i).getAlarmVideo());
        alarmList.get(i).setPath(url + imageUrl + alarmList.get(i).getPath());
    }
    Integer count = iAlarm.count(route, carNumber, carType, name, type, dateStart, dateEnd, page, 0, city);
    return Result.success(new RespData(count, alarmList));
}
```

I know it's a little bit strange at present and makes me confused a lot. Above are all the codes that the browser uses to retrieve data.
anybody, please give me some suggestions to optimize it, thanks a lot.

Comment: Run the same query on both systems with `EXPLAIN`. See what's different.

Comment: Just a note. CentOS is reaching end of life as an OS. I would suggest you switch to another operating system.

Comment: The code that represents your query is in "iAlarm.getAll".

Comment: Your SQL query includes a limit. Does your Java query?

Comment: Which table is `createTime` in?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: You should trace the SQL query generated by hibernate and compare with the one you execute in the command line.